# EIGRP vs OSPF for internal routing

Tags: routing, ip, ospf, eigrp

What's the difference bewteen EIGRP and OSPF for internal routing ?

I know that EIGRP can only be deployed on CISCO equipement, but what's the point of using it instead of OSPF on a heterogenous architecture ? It's none, what's the point of using it ?

Comment: "_...what's the point of using it [EIGRP] instead of OSPF on a heterogenous [sic] architecture ?_" You can't. If you want to use EIGRP, then it must be on a homogeneous, Cisco network.

Comment: You can use EIGRP on the CISCO equipements, and redistributes routes in OSPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real advantage that EIGRP has over OSPF is that OSPF only has an arbitrary cost as its metric, while EIGRP can take into account bandwidth, load, delay, reliability, and MTU when selecting the best route.

The OSPF cost, by default, only uses the link bandwidth. You can, of course, manually configure costs on all the links, but that doesn't scale, and it is not dynamic.

EIGRP can be configured to dynamically take into account any of the five attributes, but by default, it only uses the bandwidth and delay.